# Currency converter not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using http://fixer.io/ currency converter to convert currency.

It has worked only once and now it is not working.

I added **money.js** and the rest o fteh script a mentioned example

It is working only when I use **GBP to USD** conversion

`var rate = fx(100).from("AED").to("USD");`

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YNPZpv?editors=1010

Answer (score 2):

It is because the data returned from the AJAX call doesn't have AED rate

```
{
  "AUD": 1.4373,
  "BGN": 1.9558,
  "BRL": 3.3784,
  "CAD": 1.3894,
  "CHF": 1.0707,
  "CNY": 7.2382,
  "CZK": 27.021,
  "DKK": 7.4343,
  "GBP": 0.84945,
  "HKD": 8.0948,
  "HRK": 7.5738,
  "HUF": 308.35,
  "IDR": 13969,
  "ILS": 4.0252,
  "INR": 71.039,
  "JPY": 122.64,
  "KRW": 1251.9,
  "MXN": 22.071,
  "MYR": 4.694,
  "NOK": 8.9905,
  "NZD": 1.5024,
  "PHP": 51.811,
  "PLN": 4.3778,
  "RON": 4.5086,
  "RUB": 63.408,
  "SEK": 9.5238,
  "SGD": 1.5047,
  "THB": 37.375,
  "TRY": 3.7387,
  "USD": 1.0437,
  "ZAR": 14.241
}
```